# Is it possible to send data 1 to many using WebRTC, without customized servers?

Tags: webrtc

In concept, I want to create a simple chat environment.  Where one terminal, can send a message to anyone else in a subscribed "channel".

Is this possible using WebRTC without a customized server?

Answer (score 0):

If it is only chat without audio or video, a simple socket server would be more than enough because there is very minimal data sent. Webrtc would only make it more complex.

For webrtc you always need a server to connect all the different clients together first. So you need to program the servers to connect your webrtc connection to specific users.

also "customized servers" is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

No, server it not neccesary to start WebRTC connection.

To connect two WebRTC endpoints you must exchange SDP between peers.
SPD is string, so you can use any channel do deliver SDP to remote peer.
It can be other messanger, socket server or even email :).

But: Socket server is simple and convenient :)
If you really don't want use it, you can try POST SDP via AJAX, and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events to push it to other peer.
Another solution is to use long pooling: https://javascript.info/long-polling